Maya declaring variables are not defined, but all cases are correct
I'm trying to write a Maya table that allows the user to put in inputs and a name, and then it will spawn an object with those attributes.
import maya.cmds as cmds

def spawn_cylinder(*args):
    newobject = cmds.polyCylinder(n="newobject")
    get_attributes()
    apply_attributes()

def get_attributes(*args):
    newtx = cmds.floatField("new_x", q=True, v=True)
    newty = cmds.floatField("new_y", q=True, v=True)
    newtz = cmds.floatField("new_z", q=True, v=True)
    
    newrx = cmds.floatField("new_rx", q=True, v=True)
    newry = cmds.floatField("new_ry", q=True, v=True)
    newrz = cmds.floatField("new_rz", q=True, v=True)
    
    newsx = cmds.floatField("new_sx", q=True, v=True)
    newsy = cmds.floatField("new_sy", q=True, v=True)
    newsz = cmds.floatField("new_sz", q=True, v=True)
    
    newname = cmds.textField("renamefield", q=True, tx=True)

def apply_attributes(*args):
    for axis in ["x","y","z"]:
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".translateX", newtx)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".translateY", newty)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".translateZ", newtz)
        
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".rotateX", newrx)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".rotateY", newry)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".rotateZ", newrz)
        
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".scaleX", newsx)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".scaleY", newsy)
        cmds.setAttr("newobject" + ".scaleZ", newsz)
    
    for object in cmds.ls("newobject"):
        cmds.rename(newname)

cmds.floatField("new_x", w=60, v=0)
cmds.floatField("new_y", w=60, v=0)
cmds.floatField("new_z", w=60, v=0)

cmds.floatField("new_rx", w=60, v=0)
cmds.floatField("new_ry", w=60, v=0)
cmds.floatField("new_rz", w=60, v=0)

cmds.floatField("new_sx", w=60, v=1)
cmds.floatField("new_sy", w=60, v=1)
cmds.floatField("new_sz", w=60, v=1)

cmds.textField("renamefield", w=200)

cmds.button(l="Cylinder", w=60,h=50,c=spawn_cylinder)

I've ensured all the fields are filled out, including the name field. The expected result is that a cylinder is created with the respective attributes. However, the script brings up errors that the names are not defined.

Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 9: name 'newtx' is not defined


newtx is a local variable of the get_attributes function, it's not in scope during apply_attributes.

Why do all your functions have *args parameters that they never use?

Sorry, I wasn't sure what needed *args and what didn't.

That's pretty basic understanding of how functions work.

Yeah, it worked though once I set all the variables to global first. Thank you!

Excessive use of global variables is poor practice. If you're learning how to program, you should learn how to return values and pass arguments.

I see. I apologize, I'm still inexperienced with both Maya and Python.

I modified your code and added layouts, so now it works without errors. When you execute it, a maya window appears with translate, rotate, scale and name parameters. This is what it looks like.
from maya import cmds

class CylinderClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = cmds.window(t="Wizard", wh=(250,320))
        cmds.columnLayout()
        # Moving tx
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='tx:')
        self.tx = cmds.floatField(pre=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Moving ty
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='ty:')
        self.ty = cmds.floatField(pre=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Moving tz
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='tz:')
        self.tz = cmds.floatField(pre=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        
        # Rotating rx
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='rx:')
        self.rx = cmds.floatField(pre=1, min=-360, max=360)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Rotating ry
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='ry:')
        self.ry = cmds.floatField(pre=1, min=-360, max=360)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Rotating rz
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='rz:')
        self.rz = cmds.floatField(pre=1, min=-360, max=360)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        
        # Scaling sx
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='sx:')
        self.sx = cmds.floatField(pre=1, v=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Scaling sy
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='sy:')
        self.sy = cmds.floatField(pre=1, v=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Scaling sz
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='sz:')
        self.sz = cmds.floatField(pre=1, v=1)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        
        # Naming
        cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.text(label='nm:')
        self.txt = 'name'
        self.name = cmds.textField(text=self.txt, w=150)
        cmds.setParent('..')
        # Separator
        cmds.separator(style='double', height=30)

        # Button
        cmds.button(label="Create Cylinder", command=self.makeCylinder)
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)
        
    def makeCylinder(self, *args):
        qtx = cmds.floatField(self.tx, q=True, v=True)
        qty = cmds.floatField(self.ty, q=True, v=True)
        qtz = cmds.floatField(self.tz, q=True, v=True)
        qrx = cmds.floatField(self.rx, q=True, v=True)
        qry = cmds.floatField(self.ry, q=True, v=True)
        qrz = cmds.floatField(self.rz, q=True, v=True)
        qsx = cmds.floatField(self.sx, q=True, v=True)
        qsy = cmds.floatField(self.sy, q=True, v=True)
        qsz = cmds.floatField(self.sz, q=True, v=True)
        qnm = cmds.textField(self.name, q=True, text=True)
        
        cmds.polyCylinder(n=qnm)
        cmds.move(qtx, qty, qtz)
        cmds.rotate(qrx, qry, qrz)
        cmds.scale(qsx, qsy, qsz)
      
CylinderClass()


